# How to add newer Android Sdk's to ADT plugin (Eclipse)?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-sdk-manager

This is my first question in this site so forgive me if this is asked before.
My Laptop is very humble (Acer 5733Z) and can't run Android Studio conveniently and the CPU does not have the virtualization feature to support emulator so I use the eclipse ADT plugin for developing simple apps for android since it runs smoothly without any problems.
But the problem is that i have only up to API17 (Android 4.2) SDK installed and when I open the SDK manager to install the newer SDK' it doesn't show any newer API's as shown :
[SDK manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAXLh.jpg)

So, Is there any way to add SDK's manually or something ?
Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you need to update the "SDK Tools" and "SDK Platform-tools" entries before you can download newer SDKs. You will see those highlighted with yellow download arrows, and if you click the "Install 3 packages" button, the SDK Manager will download and upgrade those packages.

Answer (score 0):

you want to update your SDK Tools for newer version of android

latest is r24.4.1 in this version android 6 now available

you can see this link for detail of all sdk tools version
[Click here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html)